# Why Visual C++ Redistributables needed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm installing GTA 5 and it's also installed Visual C++ Redistributables. This got me curious about something, because this happens a lot.

As far as I know, these are needed for linking to VC++ libraries, but I already have .NET 4.8 installed on my system.

I thought when C++ (managed) gets compiled to MSIL, it would then just use the standard .NET Framework libraries.

So essentially the question is, since the .NET Framework libraries are present, why do additional VC++ specific libraries also need to be installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:

**".NET runtime" is to C# as "Visual C++ runtime" is to C++**

Explanation:

Applications written in C# or "managed code" require a specific version of the .NET runtime installed.  The .NET runtime not only includes the interpreter for the virtual machine code, but also provides all the standard class libraries an application developer might reference in his code.  Applications written in C# will need the .NET runtime installed on the target computer.

Applications written in C/C++ or a "native code" typically link with a set of libraries to provide the common set of functions and classes provided by the language standard (e.g. `printf` and `std::string`).  The application developer can choose to statically link these functions directly into his EXE.  But it's often advantageous to link dynamically with a DLL version of these libraries so they can be shared across the system or with binaries within the application.  Hence, the redistributable package.

Comment: Ohhh, weird! I thought all ".NET languages" compile to the same MSIL that runs on .NET Framework.  Thank you!

Comment: @katie1245 This is true for managed C++ aka [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is a [special mode of compilation for the MSVC C++ compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation?view=vs-2019). The usual way to compile C++ is to go straight to native code. Even Microsoft nowadays advises against writing application code in C++/CLI and it is intended to be used purely as a glue language for easing interacting between native C++ code (which still makes up a major part of Windows) and .NET code.

Comment: @ComicSansMS That makes sense! But I'm curious and I know this is slightly off topic now so it'll be the last thing before I stop for this question.  Is VC++ (compiled to native) the same as the gcc-g++ compiler (compiling to native)?

Comment: @katie1245 - correct.  Both Visual C++ compiler and gcc/g++ both generate native object code for the target architecture.

Answer (score 2):

C++ compiles to native code and does not use the .NET runtimes. It uses the VC++ runtime (*), which can be either statically or dynamically linked. In the latter cases, this requires the VC++ redistributables.

(*) It is technically possible to build an application with VC++ that does *not* use the VC++ runtime at all, but that sacrifices language features and is not common.

Managed flavors such as [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) compile to mixed mode assemblies, which still have an unmanaged part with the same requirements.

Comment: Ohhh, weird! I thought all ".NET languages" compile to the same MSIL that runs on .NET Framework.  Thank you!

Comment: @katie1245 Yes, except C++ is not a "*.NET language*". From Microsoft's [.NET Programming Languages](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/languages) page: "*You can write your .NET apps in C#, F#, or Visual Basic*".